# How to catch a callback error with a try catch?

Tags: javascript, async-await, try-catch

I have an async function that grabs the contents of a file, like so:

```
async function getFile (name) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(`./dir/${name}.txt`, 'utf8', function (error, file) {
      if (error) reject(error)
      else resolve(file)
    })
  })
}
```

And I call that function into a console log

`getFile('name').then( console.log )`

If I make an error, like misspelling the file name, I get this handy error:

```
(node:17246) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async 
function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not 
handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

I can fix it by doing this:

`getFile('name').then( console.log ).catch( console.log )` but is there a way to deal with the error within the callback? Perhaps a try catch? How would I do that?

Comment: Simply don't call `reject`? Figure out what you want to do if `error`, and put it inside the `readFile`?

Comment: What do you mean by "deal with the error within the callback"? More specifically, what do you want to happen when there's an error: have the code that called `getFile` deal with it or return something else?

Comment: @kirbuchi Ideally the function would have no side effects, like logging the error for example. It would do one thing and one thing only return a file or return an error.

Comment: @Costa That's exactly what it does, return the error. When you don't handle it, you get a helpful unhandled rejection warning. If you want to handle it but not log it, then use `.catch(err => { /* ignore */ })` instead of `.catch(console.log)`. (Or the equivalent `async`/`await` code, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want your function to resolve regardless of whether you got and error or not. If so you can just `resolve` in either case:

```
async function getFile (name) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    fs.readFile(`./dir/${name}.txt`, 'utf8', function (error, file) {
      if (error) resolve(error)
      else resolve(file)
    })
  })
}
```

Then you'd need to handle the errors outside, e.g.

```
getFile('name')
  .then(getFileOutput => {
    if (getFileOutput instanceof Error) {
      // we got an error
    } else {
      // we got a file
    }
  })
```

or

```
const getFileOutput = await getFile('name');
if (getFileOutput instanceof Error) {
  // we got an error
} else {
  // we got a file
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Hmm.... I now realize I may not want that. Sad face. How to keep my function from having side effects. I think I should handle the error outside, like you're saying, but perhaps it is wise to reject, and then handle the rejection outside.

Comment: The first snippet on Zach's answer is what I've seen people do normally/what I'd do. But it's up to you :)

Comment: In this case, you can replace this line: `if (error) resolve(error)` with `if (error) throw error`, and then you will have the equivalent to my answer below, in that you can catch the result of the function call (I figured this out thanks to @Bergi's edit)

Answer (score 2):

You still need to catch errors that are `rejected`.

I think it's where you call your `getFile` function from - that needs to be wrapped in a `try/catch` block

```
try {
  const result = await getFile('name')
} catch(e) {
  ... You should see rejected errors here
}
```

Or, I think this would work for your example:

```
await getFile('name').then( console.log ).catch(e => {...})
```

Testing this in the Chrome DevTools console:

```
async function test () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    throw 'this is an error';
  })
}
```

And calling it via the following:

```
await test().catch(e => alert(e))
```

Shows that this does, in fact, work!

Comment: Replacing the if (error)... else... with a try catch, didn't work. Now my error case is just undefined. Which is happening because it tries to resolve first, with file empty.

Comment: @Costa - Looking at your code `getFile('name').then( console.log )`, I think you should be 'awaiting' the result. i.e. `await getFile('name').then( console.log )`. Otherwise I adjusted the answer with a working example and it definitely works as expected